# ¿No visualiza los componentes en el emulador ni tampoco en el dispositivo físico?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design, design

estoy desarrollando una app sencilla, pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación no me visualiza los componentes en el emulador ni tampoco en el dispositivo físico (smartphone), pero los componentes si se visualizan en el diseño, ya actualicé los sdk, cambie versiones de la API 29 a la 28 y aun así sigue sin visualizarlos. Agradezco si pueden darme alguna orientación. Gracias

(cabe resaltar que también me sucede con otra app)

Este es el XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textButtonClick"
    android:theme="@style/MiButtonRaised"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/miFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@mipmap/star_ic">

</com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
```

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MiButtonRaised" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorBlanco</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlanco</item>


</style>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas usando ConstraintLayout pero no veo problema en el Layout, se deben mostrar los elementos.

Asegura que el layout correcto sea cargado en tu Activity en este caso serìa  `activity_main.xml` , puedes verificarlo en esta linea dentro de el mètodo `onCreate()`:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```